# Evitar refresh al presionar un enlace

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una pagina en el cual es un "administrador de pacientes", donde en un formulario se ingresan datos y se guardan en un objeto. Estoy usando json-server con un API, para guardar cada paciente, ya guardo todo en la API y los extraigo para mostrarlos, con JavaScript creo el HTML todo se guarda en una tabla, creo el `tr`  y usando *template literals* creo el HTML, donde le agrego los `td` y adentro los datos del objeto, creo un enlace el cual me va a eliminar ese `tr` por medio del id,(cada enlace tiene un id).
Selecciono el `tbody` (`#lista-pacientes`) y le agrego el evento *click* donde llama a la función `eliminarPacienteId` y usando `e.target.classList.contains('btn-eliminar')` verifico que se este dando *click* en el enlace de elimina, ya elimino cada `tr` con el enlace, el problema es que cada que elimino un tr, la pagina se recarga, como puedo evitar esto, ya use `href="javascript:void(0)"` en el enlace, pero pasa lo mismo.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cada que elimino un elemento desde el enlace(`btn-eliminar`), la pagina no se vuelva a recargar y solo elimine ese `tr`?

**Código donde obtengo los clientes, los recorro y los muestro. Y los elimino**

```javascript
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', mostrarPacientes)
        const listaPacientes = document.querySelector('#lista-pacientes');
        listaPacientes.addEventListener('click', eliminarPacienteId);
     
        
    
        async function mostrarPacientes(){
            const pacientes = await extrearPacientesAPI();
            
            pacientes.forEach(paciente => {
                const {nombre, telefono, fecha, hora, id} = paciente;
    
                const row = document.createElement('tr');
    
                row.innerHTML = `
                    <tr>
                        <th>${id}</th>
                        <td>${nombre}</td>
                        <td>${telefono}</td>
                        <td>${fecha}</td>
                        <td>${hora}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="editar-paciente.html?id=${id}">
                                <img src="img/editar.svg" class="icono-editar">
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-paciente="${id}" class="btn-eliminar">
                                Eliminar
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `
    
                listaPacientes.appendChild(row)
            })
}
    
function eliminarPacienteId(e){
            e.preventDefault();
    
            console.log(e.target)
            if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-eliminar')){
                const pacienteId = Number(e.target.dataset.paciente);
                const confirmarEliminar = confirm('¿ Deseas eliminar este paciente ?');
    
                if(confirmarEliminar){
                    eliminarPacienteAPI(pacienteId)
                    
                }
    
            }
}
```

**Código de la API donde extraigo los clientes y Elimino el `tr` por el ID**

```
export async function extrearPacientesAPI(){
    try {
        const respuesta = await fetch(url);
        const resultado = await respuesta.json();
        return resultado
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export async function eliminarPacienteAPI(pacienteId){
    try {
        await fetch(`${url}/${pacienteId}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

Comment: Por algún motivo usas el link y el href y no un onclick?

Comment: tendria que añadir el onclick desde el enlace? Ya he intentado hacer eso, pero no se porque motivo no puedo crear la funcion.

Comment: Puedes usar `<button onclick="funcionX()">` si usas un `<a>` siempre intentará enviar